# NSDocument read RTFD Data

Tags: cocoa, rtf, nsdocument

I am working on a text editor and I want to add RTFD support. After adding the RTFD file type to my Info.plist, I got the message that "readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error: must be overridden for your application to handle file packages."

I had a look around in the documentation and found some things, but I didn't manage to do everything..Could someone be so kind and help me out please?

```
- (BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {

    if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"Rich Text with Attachments"])  {   
        NSLog(@"Its RTFD");
        //it gets to here but I don't know how to load the rtfd data then :(
}

ofType:typeName]    return YES; }
```

Any help is apprechiated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFD is a particularly easy one, luckily.  Check out the `readRTFDFromFile:` and `writeRTFDToFile:atomically:` methods of `NSText`.

From the [NSText Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> #### readRTFDFromFile:
>
> Attempts to read the RTFD file at *path*, returning `YES` if successful and `NO` if not.
>
> `- (BOOL)readRTFDFromFile:(NSString *)path`
>
> **Discussion**
>   *path* should be the path for an `.rtf` file or an `.rtfd` file wrapper, not for the RTF file within an `.rtfd` file wrapper.

If you're coming from `NSURL`, do something like this:

```
[textView readRTFDFromFile:[[self fileURL] path]];
```

To be safe, call `[[self url] isFileURL]` first.

Comment: I tried your snippet and achieved the following: The NSDocument window was opened, the title was updated to the RTFD file's name but the NSTextView is still blank.This is my code:

 if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"Rich Text with Attachments"]) {
  NSString *urlString = [[self fileURL] absoluteString];
  NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
  [textView readRTFDFromFile:urlString];
  
  return YES;
 }

Comment: @David, you don't want the URL string, just a path to the file.  I made a quick test app, and this worked for me:  `[textView readRTFDFromFile:@"/Users/carl/Desktop/file.rtfd"]`

Comment: the reason i have an URL string is because my app is based on the NSDocument structure, NSDocument returns an URL as filepath only, which I then converted to a string...

Comment: I have by doing this: NSString *urlString = [[self fileURL] absoluteString]; and then loading it via readRTFDFromFile:.The filepath is right on NSLog, but it still wont load :(

Comment: @David, on another test, the trailing `/` is ok, just not the `file://localhost/`.

Comment: @David, that's still a URL.  Change it to `@"/Users/David/Documents/Coursework/Geography Coursework.rtfd"`.  How are you getting the URL?

Comment: still nothing...again the title of the Window updates, but the document remains blank.The URL is obtained through the [NSDocument fileURL] call which returns a NSURL.

Comment: @David, it's not that hard to convert a URL to a local path: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/path

Comment: @David, tested and works.  I'll edit the answer.  You should read some of the documentation, I think.

Comment: i know it isn't,but i already tried that (it now returns "/ReadMe.rtfd").No avail.Same result?Title changes but NSTextView does not. I am seriously wondering why it fails :/

Comment: I think my approach is wrong? because the implementation is: 
-(BOOL)readFromFileWrapper:(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapper ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError

Maybe I need to approach it differently ?

Comment: Why would you override `readFromFileWrapper:` when you don't have to?  I give up.

Comment: The compiler tells me that readFromFileWrapper:ofType:error has to be implemented and overwritten to handle file packages.

Comment: To get a path string from an `NSURL`, use `[yourURL path]` not `[yourURL absoluteString]`.

Comment: Issue solved, I barked up the wrong tree.This is the answer for NSDocument:   
mString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFDFileWrapper:fileWrapper documentAttributes:nil];

Answer (score -1):

I tried your snippet and achieved the following:

The NSDocument window was opened, the title was updated to the RTFD file's name but the NSTextView is still blank.

I was pretty convinced that my code would open it, since I got myself the URL from the NSDocument instance, converted it to an NSString and sent it to the textview...

```
if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"Rich Text with Attachments"]) {
        NSString *urlString = [[self fileURL] absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
        [textView readRTFDFromFile:urlString];

        return YES;
    }
```

The Log returned this:

```
file://localhost/Users/David/Documents/Coursework/Geography%20Coursework.rtfd/
```

So it should work?

Comment: @David, it's a little weird to answer your own question like this; please edit your original post to add more details if you like.

Comment: NSString *urlString = [[self fileURL] path];